# How do I know my maximum resolution of my graphics card? With external monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, resolution, hdmi, vga

So I have an ASUS N76V with a GeForce GT 635M graphics card. I was testing if I could use my VGA and my HDMI port simultaneously and it worked.

http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gt-635m/specifications

Here I can see that the max resolution of my screen is 2560x1600
And for the VGA port it is 2048x1536.
But what about HDMI?
And does this count when they are both used?

Kind regards

Comment: HDMI is a digital connection thus the resolution for HDMI is  2560x1600. This graphics card only has a HDMI or VGA connection.

Comment: But my laptop has a VGA and a HDMI port. So you are saying that one of the two is not connected to my graphics card?

Comment: I didn't say that.  I said this hard only has two connections a digital connection and a VGA connection.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the reference specs, not the Asus specs. Asus can limit it how they like.

Asus doesn't specify, but I would bet money they cap it at 1920x1080. They don't have to worry about folks accidentally going to high that way.

Only way to know for sure is to hook it up and test it, or ask Asus directly.